# Asp.Net Forms Authentication SSO between 4.5 and 4.6.1 web applications

Tags: iis, cookies, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.5, .net-4.6.1

Sigle-Sign-On between 4.5 framework application and 4.6.1 framework application is not working.

My current and previous web applications are hosted under the same IIS website. One is 4.5 version and another is 4.6.1 version.

But my cookie create in the new app is not authenticated under the old application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie created by both the applications will only be same if they have the same machine keys and use the same encryption methods. Please find below sample from my application. In my second application, I use the same settings and it works fine.

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate" validation="SHA1" validationKey="AutoGenerate" />
```

Comment: I added decryption="AES" also , it worked !!
IIS is taking a different config while in Auto for different .Net Frameworks